# ¿Por que no me devuelve resultado ni error?

Tags: python

Al ejecutar este código no me devuelve ni error ni resultado:

```
import numpy as np

def precio_cerveza(coste, cantidad, ingredientes):

    total = np.array(cost_list_float) @ np.array(cost_list_float)

coste = {"lupulo" : "2.5",
            "malta" : "1.5",
            "agua" : "0.006",
            "levadura" : "0.45"}

cantidad = {"lupulo" : "6u",
               "malta" : "14u",
               "agua" : "7u",
               "levadura" : "11u"}

ingredientes = {"lupulo" : "lupulo",
                   "malta" : "malta",
                   "agua" : "agua",
                   "levadura" : "levadura"}
    
cost_list = list(coste.values())
cantidad_list = list(cantidad.values())
    
cost_list_float = []
cantidad_list_float = []
for c, d in zip(cost_list, cantidad_list):
        cost_list_float.append(float(c[:-1]))
        cantidad_list_float.append(float(d[:-1]))
```

Comment: No tiene ningún `return resultado` ni `print resultado`. Es una serie de calculos que actualizan algunas variables.

Answer (score 3):

Deduzco que buscas calcular el precio e insumos de la cerveza en base a costos, cantidad e ingredientes.

La función para calcular sería

```
def precio_cerveza(coste, cantidad, ingredientes):
    cost_list = list(coste.values())
    cantidad_list = list(cantidad.values())

    cost_list_float = []
    cantidad_list_float = []
    for c, d in zip(cost_list, cantidad_list):
        cost_list_float.append(float(c[:-1]))
        cantidad_list_float.append(float(d[:-1]))

    return cost_list, cantidad_list
```

y luego ponemos los antecedentes:

```
coste = {"lupulo": "2.5",
         "malta": "1.5",
         "agua": "0.006",
         "levadura": "0.45"}

cantidad = {"lupulo": "6u",
            "malta": "14u",
            "agua": "7u",
            "levadura": "11u"}

ingredientes = {"lupulo": "lupulo",
                "malta": "malta",
                "agua": "agua",
                "levadura": "levadura"}
```

con lo cual podemos obtener

```
costos, cantidades = precio_cerveza(coste, cantidad, ingredientes)
print("Costo", costos)
print("Cantidades", cantidades)
```

produce:

```
Costo ['2.5', '1.5', '0.006', '0.45']
Cantidades ['6u', '14u', '7u', '11u']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!!!